# Importing directory tree of PNG files

Tags: qgis, raster, import, cache, directory

I have a local cache directory tree of thousands of satellite tiles in PNG format and in subfolders from -1 to 16 depending on the zoom level. I wish to import these into QGIS and be able to zoom into any level of detail.
QGIS does not give the option to import a directory into raster layer. It gives an error if I try importing into a vector layer. How can I import this directory of PNGs?

Or must the tiles be first put into a geopackage database? If so, how would this be best done in QGIS?

Comment: You just want to add them to the map?

Comment: To mostly make new maps; each directory tree is to go into it's own qgis map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add all png rasters in a folder to the map you can use pyqgis. Disable map rendering before you execute the code. It is possible QGIS will freeze, try it on one folder first..

```py
import os

filetype = '.png'
rasterfolder = r'C:\GIS\data\DEM' #Change this. All files with above filetype in this dir and all subdir to it will be added to the map
layerlist = [] #A list to hold raster layers
for root, folder, files in os.walk(rasterfolder):
    for file in files: #For every file in rasterfolder
        if file.endswith(filetype): #Check if it is a .png
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file) #Concatenate its path and filename
            rasterlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fullname, file) #Create a layer
            layerlist.append(rasterlayer) #Append to layerlist
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(layerlist) #Add all layers in the list to the map
print('Done')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and code. It works!